# How to specify custom dist folder in electron-forge

Tags: yarn-workspaces, electron-forge

I'm using yarn workspaces and my electron app is in `packages/app` All works well, apart when I run `yarn start` in `packages/app` it will produce dist folder in root not in desired `pacakges/app`. I tried to modify `package.json` in app and in root (just in case) but with no luck

```
"config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {
        "out": "packages/app/dist"
      }
    }
  }
```

just to make clear this is what I have

```
root
  |- dist
  |- packages (workspaces)
    |- app
    |  |- // I want dist here
    |
    |- module-b
```

Answer (score 1):

"Please note that you can not override the dir, arch, platform, **out** or electronVersion options as they are set by Electron Forge internally"

from: *https://www.electronforge.io/configuration*